# Is this Cron Trigger Expression valid?

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, cronexpression

```
   public static ITrigger FireEveryDayAtMidnight()
    {
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
            .WithCronSchedule("0 02 01 * * ?")
            .ForJob("myJob", "group1")
            .Build();

        return trigger;
    }
```

I have a problem thoroughly understanding Cron Trigger Expressions. I intend to schedule the above trigger to fire every day at 2 minutes past midnight. I just want to hear from people much more experienced with cron expressions if my expression above "0 02 01 * * ?", will indeed run as intended i.e run fire every day at 2 minutes past midnight

Comment: [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) might help you to build expressions and/or parse yours.

Answer (score 2):

The cron in your trigger will execute at 02:00 on the 1st of every month.

If you wish to execute it at 00:02 every day using the 7 field Quartz contrab format, use:

```
0 2 0 * * * * ?
```

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)'s a quick summary of how crons are formed, snipped from the [Cron How To on Ubuntu's site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto):

> Each of the sections is separated by a space, with the final section
>   having one or more spaces in it. No spaces are allowed within Sections
>   1-7, only between them. Sections 1-7 are used to indicate when and how
>   often you want the task to be executed. This is how a cron job is laid
>   out:
>
> second (0-59), minute (0-59), hour (0-23, 0 = midnight), day (1-31), month (1-12),
>   weekday (0-6, 0 = Sunday), year (empty, 1970-2099) command.

Comment: I'm trying to validate the examples here http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontrigger.html against the tool you linked to here http://cronchecker.net/  but they are not matching.

Comment: Expressions in Quartz can comprise of 6 or 7 fields. The extra field at the beginning is for seconds. I have updated the example above to take this into account. 0 2 0 * * * * ? would match the Quartz pattern. Does this help?